# Difference between using function in function and just using one function in python?

Tags: python, mergesort

In python, I made merge sort algorithm but it dosen't work.

```
def merge_sort(L:list):
    if len(L) > 1:
        mid = len(L) // 2
        left = merge_sort_help(L[:mid])
        right = merge_sort_help(L[mid:])
        merge(left, right)
    elif len(L) == 1:
        return L
def merge(left, right):
    ans = []
    while len(left) and len(right):
        if left[0] >= right[0]:
            ans.append(right.pop(0))
        elif left[0] < right[0]:
            ans.append(left.pop(0))
    if len(left):
        ans += left
    elif len(right):
        ans += right
    return ans
```

Error was `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`.
But when I didn't use merge function and just copy/pasted the merge function into merge_sort function(above `elif`), it worked. What's the difference between using function in function and just using one function?

Comment: what does `merge_sort_help` return?

Comment: Note that ``merge_sort`` will return ``None`` in all but one case.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to provide a [mre]? It's not clear how this code is called, when and where the error originates, what the missing code does, nor how the code looked when you "just copy/pasted the merge function into merge_sort function". In short, we have next to no idea what code and problem you are actually asking about.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference as such. Converting a block of code into function will help you with reusing it in multiple places.

The error looks like some edge case is popping up in the merge function, where it is trying to get the length of a `NoneType` object.